# Consolidate Similar Functions DRY

Tags: javascript, dry

I have these 2 functions that are very similar. I thought about using strings and `eval('Man')`, but I would love to avoid this, if possible. How can  abstract the two, so it's only one function?

```
function showMan() {
    widget.classList.add(toggle);
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: calWoman
    }).play();
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: pointsWoman
    }).play();

    pointsMan.classList.remove(toggle);
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: calMan
    }).play();
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: pointsMan
    }).play();
    mtFields();
    inputMan.focus();
}

function showWoman() {
    widget.classList.add(toggle);
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: calMan
    }).play();
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: pointsMan
    }).play();

    pointsWoman.classList.remove(toggle);
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: calWoman
    }).play();
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: pointsWoman
    }).play();
    mtFields();
    inputWoman.focus();
}
/** @todo abstract and create one function - showPerson('Man') */
```

Comment: would it be easy to pass in Man and Woman?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the excellent solutions and suggestions provided above, here is what I ended up doing, which worked best for my situation over all (least rewriting, most DRYness). Thank you very much for answering the question.

```js
function showPerson() {
  /**
   * the element being hidden should be placed in the first parameter
   * @param {object} woman - HTMLFormElement (pointsWoman)
   * @param {object} man - HTMLFormElement (pointsMan)
   * @example showPerson(pointsWoman, pointsMan);
   */

  if (arguments[0] instanceof HTMLFormElement && arguments[1] instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
    widget.classList.add(toggle);

    fx.wipeOut({
      node: arguments[0]
    }).play();

    arguments[1].classList.remove(toggle);

    fx.wipeIn({
      node: arguments[1]
    }).play();

    mtFields();
    arguments[1][0].focus();
  }
  else {
    throw new Error('You need to provide the forms to show/hide');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It'd be easier if you consolidate all your variables into an object.

```
function showPerson(sex) {
    var people = {
        woman: {
            cal: calWoman,
            points: pointsWoman,
            input: inputWoman
        },
        man: {
            cal: calMan,
            points: pointsMan,
            input: inputMan
        }
    };

    sex = sex.toLowerCase();
    var otherSex = sex === 'man' ? 'woman' : 'man';  
    var show = people[sex];
    var hide = people[otherSex]

    widget.classList.add(toggle);
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: hide.cal
    }).play();
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: hide.points
    }).play();

    show.points.classList.remove(toggle);
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: show.cal
    }).play();
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: show.points
    }).play();
    mtFields();

    show.input.focus();
}

// usage
showPerson('man');
showPerson('woman');
```

Comment: This did not work when I plugged it in. Even after I fixed the `cal = calMan`. I will debug some more tomorrow.

Comment: I have not tried yet. Will update you artery after I give it a whirl.

Comment: Thank you. I went with an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, `showPerson`, which accepts a `gender` as a parameter.

From there, you can create an object inside which encapsulates the gender-specific functions and then reference its opposite:

```
function showPerson(gender) {
    var optionsObj = {
        man: {
            cal: calMan,
            points: pointsMan,
            input: inputMan.focus,
        },
        woman: {
            cal: calWoman,
            points: pointsWoman,
            input: inputWoman.focus,
        }
    }

    gender === 'man' ? optionsObj[gender].opposite = optionsObj.woman : optionsObj[gender].opposite = optionsObj.man;

    widget.classList.add(toggle)
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: optionsObj[gender].cal,
    }).play();
    fx.wipeOut({
        node: optionsObj[gender].points
    }).play();

    optionsObj[gender].points.classList.remove(toggle);
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: optionsObj[gender].opposite.cal
    }).play();
    fx.wipeIn({
        node: optionsObj[gender].opposite.points
    }).play();
    mtFields();
    optionsObj[gender].input()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little confusing thinking about the order of everything here, but the trick isn't to break two gigantic functions down, into one, but rather to break your system down into smaller parts that can be better combined.

```
function hideNode ( node ) { fx.wipeOut({ node: node }).play(); }
function revealNode ( node ) { fx.wipeIn({ node: node }).play(); }

function showPerson (removalList, revealList, points, input) {
  widget.classList.add(toggle);
  removalList.forEach(hideNode);
  points.classList.remove(toggle);
  revealList.forEach(revealNode);
  input.focus();
}

// somewhere NORTH of your current function
var womanList = [calWoman, pointsWoman];
var manList = [calMan, pointsMan];
var revealList, removalList, input, points;

if (man) {
   removalList = womanList;
   revealList = manList;
   input = inputMan;
   points = pointsMan;
} else {
   removalList = manList;
   revealList = womanList;
   input = inputWoman;
   points = pointsWoman;
}

// alternatively, these can be stored in an object this way, and pulled by a flag, rather than by an if statement...

showPerson( removalList, revealList, points, input );
```

If you'll note, the logic has stayed very simple, by relying on passing parameters into my function.
The logic for choosing values is also pretty simple, but I've moved the need to choose outside of the function; that's somebody else's concern (even if it's a new function which does nothing but chooses and passes the appropriate values in).

I've taken the repeat steps in the function, and broken them down into smaller functions, and I'm using lists (even just lists of two), so that I can ignore the details of how many times something gets called...  ...it gets called exactly as many times as there are people you sent me.
I haven't solved the "Who calls showPerson, with what and what access...", but that's a way more specific problem to solve; wrapping up whomever is using that `if () { }` and value setting/passing is pretty quick, from here.

This is far from a clean, finished product, but what it *does* provide is a look at how you would tackle these moving parts in a larger project.

## Edit

To take this a step further, and to show that you don't need to do much in the way of rewrite, here (at least not initially), I'll add in a step further:

```
function getPersonConfig ( type ) {
  var config = {
    man: { /* ... */ },
    woman: { /* ... */ }
  };

  return config[type];
}

function showMan () {
  var config = getPersonConfig( "man" );
  showPerson( config );
}

function showWoman () {
  var config = getPersonConfig( "woman" );
  showPerson( config );
}
```

I'm using a ***slightly*** different version of my `showPerson` function there...
In it, I'm passing an object (rather than separate vars), but that's all that I'd need to change.

Look what these small, composable functions have bought me...
You haven't had to change `showMan` or `showWoman` at all.
Instead, you're hijacking what they used to be, and using them to call smaller functions which do the same job, but are now more separable and reusable.

This is a "facade" or a "veneer", and typically in engineering, it's an API or a service being talked about, but what it basically means is that when you want to update code, if you can keep the method names, the inputs and outputs and all consequences the same (from what the outside world can tell), then you can change the internal structure of your code as much as you want.

`showMan` is still being called, and the things it was doing are still being done, now, with nothing added or removed.
Same with `showWoman`.
So you've successfully kept a facade in place, while replacing the internals.

Facades can also go the other way; write the new service/API the way you want it to look to the outside world, and release that to the world with the bare minimum required to hook the old code up to the new structure, and then fill in the new functionality as you go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really like this idea, but I would have to do a good amount of rewriting to make this work, as I'm calling these `show...()` functions in several places.

Comment: Not a lot of rewriting. If you wrap the stuff that I'm setting in the `if` in a function, and then rewrite `showMan` and `showWoman`, to do nothing more than call the function which runs the `if` and fills the function.

Comment: @colecmc have another look; I haven't fixed all of your problems, but I've added an edit to show how you can use this technique, without having to do mass-rewrites everywhere `showMan` and `showWoman` are called.

Comment: Thank you. I went with an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showPerson(calPerson, pointsPerson, inputPerson) {
   //replace calWoman and calMan with calPerson

   //replace pointsMan and pointsWoman with pointsPerson

   //replace inputMan and inputWoman with inputPerson

}
```

If you can't pass it in you can use a closure to intialize a function with these references.

```
function showPerson(calPerson, pointsPerson, inputPerson) {
   function showingPersonWithReferences() {
     //replace calWoman and calMan with calPerson

     //replace pointsMan and pointsWoman with pointsPerson

     //replace inputMan and inputWoman with inputPerson
   }

   return showingPersonWithReferences;
}
```

This is a little bit of functional programming in javascript.